# Laravel yajra/Datatables action delete is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, laravel-5.1

hy, i'm now using L5 and yajra/datatables plugin, everything work fine until i create delete button to delete record, the delete button is not working
here is my controller :

```
public function data() 
{
    $news = DB::table('news')
        ->join('users', 'news.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select(['news.id', 'news.judul', 'news.gambar', 'users.name']);

    return Datatables::of($news)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($id) {
            return '<a href="news/' . $id->id . '/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
            <button class="btn-delete" data-remote="/news/' . $id->id . '">Delete</button>'; 
        })->make(true);
}
```

Here is my JS :

```
var table = $('#news-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: '{!! route('news.data') !!}',
        columns: [
            {
                "className": 'details-control',
                "orderable": false,
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            {data: 'id', name: 'news.id'},
            {data: 'judul', name: 'news.judul'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'users.name'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ],
        order: [[1, 'asc']]
    });

//problem starts here
$('#news-table').DataTable().$('.btn-delete[data-remote]').on('click', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    var url = $(this).data('remote');
    // confirm then
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'DELETE',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {method: '_DELETE', submit: true}
    }).always(function (data) {
        $('#news-table').DataTable().draw(false);
    });
});
```

the JS event for btn-delete[data-remote] is not working, it's no return error in console, but nothing happen when i click it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its maybe not working because one the moment you binding your click event on the table there isn't any elements in it. And so its not possible to bind the click event on an element named `.btn-delete[data-remote]`.

Maybe it works if you bind the click event on the table and let it trigger if clicked on `.btn-delete[data-remote]`, like:

```
$('#news-table').on('click', '.btn-delete[data-remote]', function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    var url = $(this).data('remote');
    // confirm then
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'DELETE',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {method: '_DELETE', submit: true}
    }).always(function (data) {
        $('#news-table').DataTable().draw(false);
    });
});

// or maybe this
$('#news-table').DataTable().on('click', '.btn-delete[data-remote]', function (e) { 
    ...... 
});
```

Comment: thanks yoram. it's working now.,, your answer it's helping me a lot

Comment: Thats great! This helps me a bunch of times

Answer (score 1):

I think you bind dynamic data with your table so it will not effect directly on `click`. So you may use `$('body')` or `$(document)` to trigger `click` event. Also you might need to comment/remove  `e.preventDefault();` . This also stop further process.

So updated code will be like :

```
//problem starts here
$('body').on('click', $('#news-table').DataTable().$('.btn-delete[data-remote]'),  function (e) { 
    //e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    var url = $(this).data('remote');
    // confirm then
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'DELETE',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {method: '_DELETE', submit: true}
    }).always(function (data) {
        $('#news-table').DataTable().draw(false);
    });
});
```

Comment: @ARUNMadathil Great

Answer (score 0):

This is because delete button cannot binding before the datatables being constructed.

solution is need to wait after datatables DOM events

official solution from https://datatables.net/reference/event/

```
$('#myTable').on('draw.dt', function () {
    alert('Table redrawn');
    // do the button binding work..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in very simple way

**btn-delete** is class that you defined in your href

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn-delete', function () {
  // do your stuff here
});
```