# delete users in yajra laravel datatables

Tags: laravel, datatable

hy, i'm new to laravel now using L5 and yajra/datatables plugin.when I click on delete button it gives an error "tokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:"
my code is

controller.php

```
return Datatables::of($users)
    ->addColumn('action', function ($id) {
               return '<button class="btn-delete" data-remote="localhost/blog/public/delete/' . $id->id . '">Delete</button>'; })
                ->make(true);
```

in view

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#users-table').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: '{!! route("data") !!}',
    columns: [
        {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
        {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
        {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
        {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
        {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
        {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
    ]
});
$('#users-table').on('click', '.btn-delete[data-remote]', function (e) { 
e.preventDefault();
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
var url = $(this).data('remote');
// confirm then
$.ajax({
    url:'delete/{id}' ,
    type: 'DELETE',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {method: '_DELETE', submit: true}
}).always(function (data) {
    $('#users-table').DataTable().draw(false);
});
});
});

</script>
```

in route.php

```
Route::get('delete/{id}',array('as'=>'delete',      'uses'=>'EditController@delete'));
```

I take reference from [Laravel yajra/Datatables action delete is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370240/laravel-yajra-datatables-action-delete-is-not-working)

I tried this

```
$('#users-table').on('click', '.btn-delete[data-remote]', function (e) { 
e.preventDefault();
var id = $(this).attr('id');
alert(id);
$.ajaxSetup({
```

it gives "undefined"

its not working for me..please help..

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the following in your  html:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

You should definitely take a look at this page to understand how this works: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: where should I add <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> in my controller or view?

Comment: In your view, between the <head></head> tags

Comment: I add it in master blade and It gives MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:

Comment: I already post my route for delete method                                                                                                          Route::get('delete/{id}',array('as'=>'delete','uses'=>'EditController@delete'));

Comment: this is my delete method in controller

public function delete($id) {
    try {
        //main table delte
        $var = User::find($id);
        $var->delete();

        return redirect()->route('edit');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error('EditController->delete' . $e->getMessage());
    }

}

Comment: Well, try to change the route by Route::delete('delete/{id}',array('as'=>'delete','uses'=>'EditController@delete')); and delete this line in your javascript data: `{method: '_DELETE', submit: true}`

Comment: FatalErrorException in EditController.php line 58: Call to a member function delete() on a non-object

Comment: Well, your User::find($id) doesn't return anything... Try to debug the $id var, and verify that it is present on your database :/

Comment: when I click on delete button it goes to http://localhost/blog/public/delete/{id}. and if I manually provide id like http://localhost/blog/public/delete/13 then it shows me data from table when Route::get('delete/{id}',array('as'=>'delete','uses'=>'EditController@delete'));  but if I change route to Route::delete('delete/{id}',array('as'=>'delete','uses'=>'EditController@delete'‌​));  then it gives error of MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:

Comment: its done..I removed  return redirect()->route('edit'); from delete method

Answer (score 0):

The `tokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53:` error means that either your csrf token has expired or that you are not sending this to the server when doing a post request. I'm guessing the second.

When doing a ajax post request to the server you need to include a parameter `_token` in your data. You can get the current csrf token for this user using `csrf_token()`.

Another option is to add X-CSRF-TOKEN header to your ajax setup. [The Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-x-csrf-token) explains how to do this.